# writing long text in excel workbook using interop throws error?

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, excel, com-interop

I am writing long text (1K to 2K characters long, plain xml data) into a cell in excel workbook.
The below statement throws COM error **Exception from HRESULT: 0x800A03EC**

```
range.set_Value(Type.Missing, data);
```

If I copy paste the same xml manually into excel it just works fine ,but the same does not work progamatically.
If I strip the text to something like 100/300 chars it works fine.

Comment: I'm using Excel 2010 and VSTO 4.0 and it doesn't have such problem. What you are using?

Comment: @Sean my answer contains C# code and the article linked contains VB code, as you've asked for in revision 3.

Comment: My initial thought would be to split the data into a number of different cells (say 100/300 chars each) and then merge those... Sloppy work around, but I think it could work

Comment: What version of Excel are you using?

Answer (score 5):

There is a limit (somehwere between 800 and 900 chars if i remember correctly) that is nearly impossible to get around like this.

Try using an ole connection and inserting the data with an SQL command. That might work better for you.  you can then use interop to do any formatting if necessary.

Comment: yep, The limit is 911 characters. Not sure whats the solution to this.

Answer (score 5):

the following KB article explains that the max limit is 911 characters. I checked the same on my code it does work for string upto 911 chars.

http://support.microsoft.com/kb/818808

The work around mentioned in this article recommends to make sure no cell holds more than 911 characters. thats lame!

Answer (score 4):

Good Ole and excel article: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/316934

The following code updates a private variable that is the number of successful rows and returns a string which is the path to the excel file.

Remember to use `Path` from `System.IO;`!

`string tempXlsFilePathName;
            string result = new string;`

```
        string sheetName;
        string queryString;

        int successCounter;

        // set sheetName and queryString
        sheetName = "sheetName";
        queryString = "CREATE TABLE " + sheetName + "([columnTitle] char(255))";

        // Write .xls
        successCounter = 0;
        tempXlsFilePathName = (_tempXlsFilePath + @"\literalFilename.xls");
        using (OleDbConnection connection = new OleDbConnection(GetConnectionString(tempXlsFilePathName)))
        {
            OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(queryString, connection);
            connection.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();

            yourCollection.ForEach(dataItem=>
            {
                string SQL = "INSERT INTO [" + sheetName + "$] VALUES ('" + dataItem.ToString() + "')";
                OleDbCommand updateCommand = new OleDbCommand(SQL, connection);
                updateCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
                successCounter++;
            }
            );

            // update result with successfully written username filepath
            result = tempXlsFilePathName;
        }

        _successfulRowsCount = successCounter;
        return result;
```

N.B. This was edited in a hurry, so may contain some mistakes.

Answer (score 2):

To solve this limitation, only writing/updating one cell at a time and dispose the Excel com object immediately. And recreate the object again for writing/updating the next cell.

I can confirm this solution is working in VS2010 (VB.NET project) with Microsoft Excel 10.0 Object Library (Microsoft Office XP)

Answer (score 0):

This limitation is supposed to have been removed in Excel 2007/2010. Using VBA the following works

```
Sub longstr()
    Dim str1 As String
    Dim str2 As String
    Dim j As Long

    For j = 1 To 2000
        str1 = str1 & "a"
    Next j
    Range("a1:a5").Value2 = str1
    str2 = Range("a5").Value2
    MsgBox Len(str2)
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll start by saying I haven't tried this myself, but my research says that you can use QueryTables to overcome the 911 character limitation.

This is the primary post I found which talks about using a record set as the data source for a QueryTable and adding it to a spreadsheet: http://www.excelforum.com/showthread.php?t=556493&p=1695670&viewfull=1#post1695670.

Here is some sample C# code of using QueryTables: [import txt files using excel interop in C# (QueryTables.Add)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2793975/import-txt-files-using-excel-interop-in-c-sharp-querytables-add).